# iOS texture repeating for half npot texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I have a texture 4x300 (half-npot) that I would like to use for a 500x300 sprite.
I set wrapS to GL_REPEAT and wrapT to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE since I only need one side to repeat.
However, all I get is a black square.
When I change the dimensions of my texture to 4x512 (pot) the image is drawn correctly.

Is there any way on iOS to use the trimmed image (4x300) with **only one side repeating** or do I have to expand it to be completely in power of two dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenGL ES, NPOT textures cannot have REPEAT mode. See:

> In OpenGL ES 2.0, textures can have non-power-of-two (npot)
>   dimensions. In other words, the width and height do not need to be a
>   power of two. However, OpenGL ES 2.0 does have a restriction on the
>   wrap modes that can be used if the texture dimensions are not power of
>   two. That is, for npot textures, the wrap mode can only be
>   GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE and the minification filter can only be GL_NEAREST
>   or GL_LINEAR (in other words, not mipmapped). The extension
>   GL_OES_texture_npot relaxes these restrictions and allows wrap modes
>   of GL_REPEAT and GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT and also allows npot textures to
>   be mipmapped with the full set of minification filters.

Also, there is no such thing as half-NPOT texture. Texture can be POT or not, both dimensions are always considered.